# Метавычисление типов в Boost MPL

Tags: c++, boost, метапрограммирование, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть задача:

*Дана последовательность типов. Проверить, что все они являются классами и упорядочить их так, чтобы производные классы находились раньше их базовых. Для полученной последовательности проверить, что все классы являются производными от последнего.*

Реализовать решение необходимо с помощью boost::mpl.
В данный момент у меня есть Swap, которая меняет местами 2 элемента в последовательности, например в mpl::vector:

```
template< typename Seq, typename First, typename Second >
struct swap {
private:
    typedef typename begin<Seq>::type begin;
    typedef typename end<Seq>::type   end;
    typedef typename clear<Seq>::type empty_container;

// Insert values from begin to first
typedef typename
    copy<
    iterator_range< begin, First >,
    back_inserter< empty_container >
    >::type prefix;

// Insert second value 
typedef typename
    push_back<
    prefix, typename
    deref< Second >::type
    >::type prefixSecond;

// Insert values from first+1 to second
typedef typename
    copy<
    iterator_range< typename next< First >::type, Second >,
    back_inserter< prefixSecond >
    >::type prefixSecondMiddle;

// Insert first value
typedef typename
    push_back<
    prefixSecondMiddle, typename
    deref< First >::type
    >::type prefixSecondMiddleFirst;

// Insert values from second+1 to end
typedef typename
    copy<
    iterator_range< typename next< Second >::type, end >,
    back_inserter< prefixSecondMiddleFirst >
    >::type prefixSecondMiddleFirstSuffix;

public:
     typedef prefixSecondMiddleFirstSuffix type;
};
```

Вот пример использования:

```
typedef typename boost::mpl::next<myvector::begin>::type first;
typedef typename boost::mpl::next<first>::type second;
typedef swap<myvector, first, second>::type res;
```

И предикат, который проверяет, что первый элемент является родителем второго:

```
template< typename T1, typename T2 >
struct compare_two{
    static const bool value = is_base_of<T1, T2>::value;
};
```

Теперь, допустим, у нас дан список типов:

```
class base1 {};

class child1 : base1 {};

class child2 : child1 {};

class child3 : child2 {};

typedef vector<child2, child1, base1, child3> vec;
```

Надо, чтобы после применения метафункции получилось: 
    child3, child2, child1, base1

Как я понимаю, надо просто отсортировать вектор, меняя соответствующие типы местами, если первый - предок второго. Подскажите, как реализовать это средствами Boost MPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
#include <boost/mpl/sort.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/count_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

struct A {};
struct B: A {};
struct C: B {};
struct D: A {};
struct E: C, D {};

// Функция сревнения - базовый класс меньше наседника
struct is_base_of_fn{
    template <class Base, class Derived> struct apply{
        using type = boost::is_base_of<Base, Derived>;
    };
};
struct is_class_fn{
    template <class T> struct apply{
        using type = boost::is_class<T>;
    };
};

template <class Seq>
using is_seq_of_class = mpl::bool_<mpl::count_if<Seq, is_class_fn>::type::value == mpl::size<Seq>::value>;

using input_type_set = mpl::vector<E,B,D,C,A>;
static_assert(is_seq_of_class<input_type_set>::value, "");

using outpur_type_set = typename mpl::sort<input_type_set, is_base_of_fn>::type;
static_assert(mpl::equal<outpur_type_set, mpl::vector<A,B,D,C,E>>::value, "");
```

P.S. Рекомендую к прочтению [эту](http://www.pdimov.com/cpp2/simple_cxx11_metaprogramming.html) статью (про метопрограммирование, не про mpl)

Comment: Да, именно то что нужно! Благодарю за ответ и статью. Все-таки это очень мозгоубивательная тема)